# Can I tell MSBuild where to look for assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a `UsingTask` which is a dll .. that references some dll which is NOT in the same directory as the using-task-dll.

eg.

`<UsingTask TaskName="FooAwesome" AssemblyFile="$(SolutionDir)packages\FooAwesome\lib\NET20\FooAwesome.dll" />`

Error: FooAwesome.dll requires Foo.Core.dll

And the Core does exist ...

```
\Solution
    \packages
        \FooAwesome
        \Foo.Core
```

So how can i tell me msbuild.proj file, that even though i'm using `FooAwesome` .. i know that it needs `Foo.Core` and it can find that dll ... ~here~.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work you'd need to change the assembly probing behavior of MsBuild.  To my knowledge there is on way to do that.  I think your best options here are the following

1. Use ILMerge so that the task is contained in one assembly
2. Strongly name + GAC the assemblies which will allow them to be found during probing

Personally I would opt for #1